# How to turn off printing result of python "sh" library

Tags: linux, python-3.x, sh, supervisord

I'm working on services with Python, when I try to get status of a service with Python `sh` library, It will return results in a variable like so:

```
import sh
status = str(sh.service('nginx','status'))
if 'active' in status:
    print('ready')
```

It works fine, but when I try to get status of `supervisor` service it will print all the results in the terminal and destroys my command outputs.

So how to turn off this result which prints in terminal?

Comment: it's`sh.service('nginx','status')` that is printing ?

Comment: @MMF about `nginx` it works fine. but about `supervisor` is doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to [redirect](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#redirection) the output.

Either to /dev/null:

```
sh.service('nginx','status', _out='/dev/null')
```

or to a `StringIO` object for you to check the output:

```
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
sh.service('nginx','status', _out=buffer)
output = buffer.getvalue()
```

Use `_err` to redirect stderr output.

Comment: Dear, It still shows this error `sh.ErrorReturnCode_3` or `RAN: /usr/sbin/service supervisor status`

Comment: *Where* does it show that? Did you try capturing `_err` as well?

Comment: The exit code is an [exception](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/exit_codes.html#exit-codes) you can catch with `try: ... except sh.ErrorReturnCode:`

Answer (score 0):

Also it would be handled by (helps to avoid printing on terminal):

```
try:
    ...
except shErrorReturnCode:
    ...
```